# ObjectListView wxPython: how to show a wx.Color

Tags: python, wxpython, objectlistview-python

I am using wxPython ObjectListView and it is very easy to use. Now I need to render a wx.Color as a column but I haven't found a way in the documentation. Basically I have list of items each of them have the following attributes: name, surname and hair color. Hair color is a RGB color and I would like to show it as a column in my ObjectListView.

Is there a way to do it ?
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

The answer appears to be **No**. The closest thing I could find was the following piece of documentation:

- http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/python/recipes.html#how-can-i-change-the-colours-of-a-row

However, this would only allow you to change the first column's background color. I attempted to do just that and that did not work either. You might want to take a look at the **UltimateListctrl**, which is a custom widget. Unfortunately, it's API is not the same as OLV.

Answer (score 0):

For the future: what I did was to show the color as a **background** of the row of the list.